# How to invoke all option values from select with cypress/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, automated-tests, cypress

i am trying to get all `values` under `select tag` in order to have an array.
This is my code:

```
cy.get('[data-tab-name-prefix="selectedFonds[0]]')
  .scrollIntoView()
  .should('be.visible')
  .find('[name="selectedFonds[0][name]"]')
  .find('option')
  .invoke('attr', 'value').then($options => {
    cy.log($options)
})
```

```html
<div data-tab-name-prefix="selectedFonds[0]"> 
       <div class= something>
       <div class= something else>
          <select class=form-control name="selectedFonds[0][name]">
              <option value="first value"> First Value </option>
              <option value="second value"> Second Value </option>
              <option value="third value"> Third Value </option>
              <option value="forth value"> Forth Value </option>
          </select>
       </div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

The problem is that it returns only the first option... not all of them.

Comment: Not sure if it's the issue, but have you tried closing your `<option>` tags? `<option value="first value">First Value</option>` Currently, your HTML has only the opening tags, so you rely on the browser inserting the closing tags, which might conflict with .find()

Comment: my fault, o wrote this code as an example and forgot to add the closing tag for option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.invoke('attr', 'value')` is causing the problem, it changes the array of options to a single value.

Move the `attr()` call inside the `.then()`.

```js
const expectedValues = ['First value', 'Second value', 'Third value', 'Fourth value']

cy.get('[data-tab-name-prefix="selectedFonds[0]]')
  .scrollIntoView()
  .should('be.visible')
  .find('[name="selectedFonds[0][name]"]')
  .find('option')
  .then($options => {
    const values = [...$options].map(option => option.getAttribute('value').trim()) 
    return values
  })
  .should('deep.eq', expectedValues)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to target the element with the data attribute then do `within()`. Then target the select element and do `children()`. Followed by a `each()` block to iterate over every option element.

```
const values = ['first value', 'second value', 'third value', 'fourth value']
cy.get('[data-tab-name-prefix="selectedFonds[0]]')
.scrollIntoView()
.should('be.visible')
.within( ($el) => {
  cy.get('select')//based on your HTML you have only one select inside this div
  .should('be.visible')
  .children()
  .each( ($el, index) => {
    cy.get($el)
    .should('have.value', values[index])
  })
})
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `.within()` if you are only drilling down to one child element. You can continue the parent chain with `.find()`